# Any one know why changes made to a .aspx page in the designer are not saved by visual studio 2008?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

im developing an asp.net website application but suddenly all changes i make to the page in the visual studio designer are not being saved for some reason. Every thing i do in the code behind file is saved with out any problem, also if i edit the .aspx file but in sourceview, the changes are saved, but if i drag a control from the toolbox onto the page designer and set some properties and then save, nothing will have been saved when i close and re-open the page, all changes are lost. Its confusing and i have no idea why.

Edit: also this happens on only one aspx file. All the other files edits are saved.

Edit: I have tried the hotfix here with no luck [http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2009/03/23/hotfix-for-design-view-does-not-update-html-and-to-designer-inserts-a-lot-of-nbsp.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20120618013613/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/webdevtools/archive/2009/03/23/hotfix-for-design-view-does-not-update-html-and-to-designer-inserts-a-lot-of-nbsp.aspx)

Comment: You're not editing auto-generated code are you?

Comment: What do you mean by auto-generated code in this context? am doing some thing like ) Drag an asp button control onto a .aspx form, set its text property to "Button1", save and close form. Re-open the .aspx file and find that the button is not there(was not saved).

Comment: I meant editing the form's automatically-generated code, but it doesn't look like it according to your description. Most likely a bug

Comment: Try small tricks, like creating a button in another form, changing the text there and pasting it in the desired form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have any of the auto-generated files open in the editor, this can stop the designer from persisting its changes.

Comment: Actually no other file is open. i have reached as far as restarting windows!!

Answer (score 1):

I think it is just a bug in visual studio.  I have also experienced this behaviour, you edit things in design view then switch back to source view and the markup does not reflect the cahanges you made in design view.  I have noticed it particulary when adding/editing columns in a gridview.  Sometimes it works, sometimes not.  I have never been able to work out a pattern.